# How to set secret environment variable with logging commands in TFS Release

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm passing a secret Release Task Variable to a PowerShell script and trying to set that value as an **environment variable** using [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) so I can use it in other tasks in the same Release. I'm able to do this with a non-secret variable, but not with a secret one.

So, the following is working (I can see it using `ls env:` and also use it to connect to a tfs instance as a Personal Access Token) when PAT is a non-secret variable:

Inline Script  Arguments: `-token "$(PAT)"`

```
Param(
   [string]$token
)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_TOKEN;]$token"
```

I can only use the environment variable set above if I use it in a subsequent powershell task - it's not available within the task where PAT is passed.

But the following does not seem to be working when PAT is a secret variable:

Inline Script Arguments: `-token "$(PAT)"`

```
Param(
   [string]$token
)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_TOKEN;issecret=true]$token"
```

(Note:  I also tried changing API_TOKEN to something else like MYTOKEN, in case API_TOKEN is reserved, but still don't see MYTOKEN var at all if I do `ls env:` in a subsequent PowerShell task.)

How can I set an environment variable to a secret value passed from a Release Task, for use by that task or by other tasks in the Release?  In other words, when or how can I access the environment variable set by the above-referenced logging commands with `issecret=true`?  (I'm not actually sure I'm setting it properly, since I can't see it, but I assume I am since the non-secret version works.)

Not sure if it matters, but I **have** ticked the box in the release definition that says "Allow scripts to access OAuth token".

**Update**

There is more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell), but it's very confusing.  I couldn't figure out how to set and access a secret environment variable - I suspect they are not actually environment variables, but in that case I don't understand why the logging commands are needed at all, since we can already pass secret variables to scripts.  I was able to workaround by passing the secret variable from the Release Task directly to the PowerShell script, and then from there to other scripts, instead of trying to set/access the value as an environment variable.

Comment: I'm not sure this will make a difference, but in the examples they use issecret=true without the ; at the end.

Comment: Another thing that you could try is to change the variable name, since API_TOKEN is a reserved variable used when you check the "Allow scripts to access oauth token". See if that works. Please let me know

Comment: Re: extra semicolon: Thanks, tried that and doesn't help; removing the extra semi-colon from my question.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang Thanks for the suggestions; I tried them and edited my question with the results (didn't work)

Comment: OK, instead trying to see if it is there listing your environment variables, have you tried to directly access it in a next powershell script by $env:API_TOKEN? I read in some place that secret variables are not created until they are used (not sure)

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow morning... I've tried that with API_TOKEN, but not with MYTOKEN

Comment: Oddly, `$env:MYTOKEN` from inside the PowerShell script gives me nothing, but `echo $(MYTOKEN)` gives asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the logging command also works for secret variables (what you tried should work). As the logging command usage mentions:

> When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved
>   as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not passed
>   into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as inputs.

You can use the script `echo $(API_TOKEN)` instead of `ls env:` (since secret variables are not showing by the command `ls env:`), then you will get `********`.

And for the use of the secret variable `$(API_TOKEN)` in your following release tasks, the value should be passed as inputs (as the usage mentions).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that quote, but it doesn't seem accurate - the variable doesn't simply get "masked out from the log" - it doesn't appear at all, and I've seen them appear in `ls env:` masked out before, although I guess that must have been from Build, not Release, and it behaves differently in the two?

Comment: You seem to be correct about `echo $(API_TOKEN)`, it's giving me some asterisks, although I don't understand why.  $(API_TOKEN) is notation used in build task arguments, I wasn't aware could also be used from inside a PowerShell script.

Comment: I can get it to echo asterisks from the PowerShell script using `echo $(API_TOKEN)`, but I don't think that's an environment variable, is it?  When I use process.env["API_TOKEN"] from a node CLI called from the powershell task, it claims the environment variable still does not exist, and I still can't see any evidence that it does, since $env:API_TOKEN still gives nothing.  How do I set the API_TOKEN as an environment variable?

Comment: Oh, I found some better documentation on this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#SecretVariables  where I think it elaborates on what you're talking about.  Working through it now.

Comment: I was not able to get this working. The documentation is at best very confusing, and possibly just wrong.  Since I can just pass a secret variable directly to a script, I changed some other scripts to receive the API_TOKEN as a parameter instead of trying to read from the environment.

Comment: @pabrams `API_TOKEN` is a user defined variable in your release definition. And when execute the logging command `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_TOKEN;issecret=true]$token"`, the user defined variable `API_TOKEN` convert to be a secret variable. And you can not decrypt it into environment variable. And what do you mean "pass a secret variable directly to a script"? Can you  show your detail steps?

Comment: @ Marina Liu   >> "And you can not decrypt it into environment variable" - this is the part that did not seem clear in the documentation. I thought the purpose of that setvariable logging command was to set an **environment** variable, but it seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @ Marina Liu >> "Can you show your detail steps"   I edited my powershell script to accept a "Token" parameter, and to pass that parameter to a node script it calls (had to edit the node script as well, of course), instead of trying to read it from the environment variable.  Then, in the arguments field of my Powershell script call in the Release task, I just set `-Token $(PAT)`, where PAT is a secret variable.

Comment: @ Marina Liu  >> "API_TOKEN is a user defined variable in your release definition. And when execute the logging command Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_TOKEN;issecret=true]$token", the user defined variable API_TOKEN convert to be a secret variable."         I guess I'm not understanding the purpose of logging commands, then.  Why would I want to convert a non-secret variable to a secret variable AFTER passing to the agent?  Doesn't that mean it could appear in plain-text in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a secret **environment** variable using the mentioned logging commands.

Comment: The documentation doesn't explicitly *say* you can do that, but the non-secret logging command sets an environment variable, so I think most people will assume that the issecret=true version of the logging command will do the same, since the documentation doesn't seem to say it won't.